# chaining sort and filter not working javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, filter

I have an array. I want to sort and filter the array. I had try to chain `.sort()` and `.filter()`. The `.sort()` is working good, but not with the `.filter()`. Here is my example data and function that I had made. Whats goes wrong here?

```js
const data = [{
  name: 'John',
  date: '24 April 2001',
  sex: 'male'
}, {
  name: 'steve',
  date: '12 August 2012',
  sex: 'male'
}, {
  name: 'natasha',
  date: '13 October 1992',
  sex: 'female'
}, {
  name: 'chris',
  date: '8 September 2004',
  sex: 'remain unknown'
}]

sortAndFilter = (arr, orderBy, order, filterBy, filterValue, dataType) => {

  let result;
  if (filterValue === '') {
    if (dataType === 'string') {
      switch (order) {
        case 'asc':
          result = arr.sort((a, b) => a[orderBy].localeCompare(b[orderBy]));
          break;
        case 'dsc':
          result = arr.sort((a, b) => b[orderBy].localeCompare(a[orderBy]));
          break;
        default:
          result = arr.sort((a, b) => a[orderBy].localeCompare(b[orderBy]));
      }
    } else if (dataType === 'date') {
      switch (order) {
        case 'asc':
          result = arr.sort((a, b) => new Date(a[orderBy]) - new Date(b[orderBy]));
          break;
        case 'dsc':
          result = arr.sort((a, b) => new Date(b[orderBy]) - new Date(a[orderBy]));
          break;
        default:
          result = arr.sort((a, b) => new Date(a[orderBy]) - new Date(b[orderBy]));
      }
    }
  } else {
    if (dataType === 'string') {
      switch (order) {
        case 'asc':
          result = arr.sort((a, b) => a[orderBy].localeCompare(b[orderBy])).filter(el => el[filterBy] === filterValue);
          break;
        case 'dsc':
          result = arr.sort((a, b) => b[orderBy].localeCompare(a[orderBy])).filter(el => el[filterBy] === filterValue);
          break;
        default:
          result = arr.sort((a, b) => a[orderBy].localeCompare(b[orderBy])).filter(el => el[filterBy] === filterValue);
      }
    } else if (dataType === 'date') {
      switch (order) {
        case 'asc':
          result = arr.sort((a, b) => new Date(a[orderBy]) - new Date(b[orderBy])).filter(el => el[filterBy] === filterValue);
          break;
        case 'dsc':
          result = arr.sort((a, b) => new Date(b[orderBy]) - new Date(a[orderBy])).filter(el => el[filterBy] === filterValue);
          break;
        default:
          result = arr.sort((a, b) => new Date(a[orderBy]) - new Date(b[orderBy])).filter(el => el[filterBy] === filterValue);
      }
    }
  }

  return result;
}

sortAndFilter(data, 'name', 'asc', 'sex', 'male', 'string');
console.log('this is not filtered: ', data);

const finalData = sortAndFilter(data, 'name', 'asc', 'sex', 'male', 'string');

console.log('this one is sorted and filtered: ', finalData);
```

that is my approach. Whats wrong? or maybe, is there any better approach to achieve this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: seems working fine?

Comment: the filter isn't

Comment: how come? Please provide some example like what are you expecting and what is showing?

Comment: sortAndFilter(data, 'name', 'asc', 'sex', 'male', 'string');, i expect the result is only john and steve, and the order is john, then steve since i order it by the name and ascending.

Comment: If you run the snippet, that's what you get. However, sort mutates arrays, and filter does not... So if you check your original argument, it will have been sorted, but not filtered. The return value will be filtered, though.

Comment: @Akza ``(2) [{…}, {…}]0: {name: "John", date: "24 April 2001", sex: "male"}1: {name: "steve", date: "12 August 2012", sex: "male"}length: 2__proto__: Array(0)`` i am getting this?

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi what I was doing before is call the function => sortAndFilter(data, 'name', 'asc', 'sex', 'male', 'string'); then console.log(data);. So, as Garret said, filter did not mutate the array. So, the work arround is, I have to store the result in a variable first, rather than see if the 'data' variable changing or not

Comment: @GarrettMotzner you are right. the array did not mutate by filtering. Its already work, but I have to store to a new variable first, rather than see if the original variable already sorted and filtered or not. Thank you Garret and Anik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @GarretMotzner and @AnikIslamAbhi for help me in the comment section. Garret already point out whats going wrong. The function is not wrong, but I just have to store the filtered array in a new variable. Because, .filter() did not mutate the array. I've update the questions include the answer above

Comment: I would say that because you are doing the sort, you probably want to do a shallow clone on the array first, so that you don't end up mutating the array. That will probably save you some bugs in the future.

Comment: @GarrettMotzner noted. Thank you for your advice. I really appreciate it